# Oracle - dynamically choose number of columns to add in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a two part question. I have a base table that looks like this:

```
DATE          ID    START_DATE    QTY     ROW
2011-01-31    1     2009-04-30    40      1
2011-01-31    1     2009-10-31    5       2
2011-01-31    1     2010-01-15    10      3
2011-01-31    2     2009-09-15    50      1
2011-01-31    3     2010-05-25    20      1
2011-01-31    3     2010-06-01    10      2
2011-01-31    3     2010-09-01    200     3
```

I want to expand out rows into columns, adding two columns for each row (QTY and START_DATE) so that each date + ID has only one line:

```
DATE        ID    SD1         QTY1  SD2         QTY2  SD3         QTY3
2011-01-31  1     2009-04-30  40    2009-10-31  5     2010-01-15  10
2011-01-31  2     2009-09-15  50    NULL        NULL  NULL        NULL
2011-01-31  3     2010-05-25  20    2010-06-01  10    2010-09-01  200
```

Right now I have up to 44 that I need to add (MAX(ROW)), but in the future there could be more. I can manually add the 44 by doing:

```
  max(CASE WHEN ROW = 1 THEN q.START_DATE END) AS SD1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ROW = 1 THEN q.QTY END) AS QTY1,
  max(CASE WHEN ROW = 2 THEN q.START_DATE END) AS SD2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ROW = 2 THEN q.QTY END) AS QTY2,
```

...

```
max(CASE WHEN ROW = n THEN q.START_DATE END) AS SDn,
SUM(CASE WHEN ROW = n THEN q.QTY END) AS QTYn
```

My first question, if I fix the number at say 50, is there a clean way for me to add those 100 columns in my code, or do I just need to explicitly show all 100 lines?

Second question, is there a way for me to use MAX(ROW) to tell the statement how many columns to add? Meaning if MAX(ROW) = 10, add SD1 - SD10 and QTY1 - QTY10. But if on next run MAX(ROW) = 100, add SD1 - SD100, QTY1 - QTY100

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an option to use pivot tables in, for example, Excel, and connect to the database through an external data source?

Comment: No, for a couple reasons. The base table is a couple million rows so it wouldn't fit in Excel. Also, that would require me to move files across VMs, and this process needs to be automated

Comment: Is it enough to use the simpler [pivot syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1)?